# Dropdownlist in DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've added a DropDownList control to a DetailsView, and I'm trying to get it to bind to a "State" parameter for my update/insert methods.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="States" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("State") %>'>
<asp:ListItem Value="NY">New York</asp:ListItem>
....
</asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

I have populated the DropDownList with the 50 states, so they aren't bound to any table and are static items. I just want to be able to select a state when editing, and when I hit edit, it should run the stored procedure to edit and take the value of the DropDownList as the argument for @State.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
'States' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the 
list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

I researched the issue but some posts suggested using "Eval" instead of "Bind" or adding some null values, but that didn't fix my issue. Do you guys have any ideas/suggestions on how I could go about getting rid of this error?

Comment: `when I hit edit` shouldn't you be looking at `EditTemplate` instead?

Comment: Yes, what I meant was that after you fill in the EditTemplate, then you click the update button and it should updated.

Answer (score 2):

If the ListItems are static (i.e. defined in the markup) i believe you should post them too.
Remember the correct syntax for ListItems is

```
<asp:ListItem Value="value" Text="displayText"></asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: I updated the OP with a single list item. All the other items have the same structure; just different text. I believe that format is also correct, right?

Comment: Check if there are registers in your data source that have a "State" value not listed in the ListItems.

Answer (score 0):

this error turns up if some values in your table in the database does not match your listitem value..so check your table entries

Answer (score 0):

Bind it to the item template value e.g.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then you can have:

```
InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="States" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("State") %>'>
<asp:ListItem Value="NY">New York</asp:ListItem>
....
</asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```